# NSRegularExpression for @user mentions does not return matches

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to find matches for @user mentions in Swift in a string I have, and I'm using the following regex to do so:

```
let str = "Hello @user how@are we doing today? @ @"
let regexPattern = "\\B@[\\w.]*"

if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.useUnicodeWordBoundaries) {
    let noOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: str, options: .init(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count))
    print("Regex is valid. No of matches = \(noOfMatches)")
}
```

The code above returns 0 matches. Removing the `options: NSRegularExpression.Options.useUnicodeWordBoundaries`, returns 3 matches, while I'm expecting 2, the `@user` and the standalone `@` at the end of the string (the @ after the emoji should not be matched).

Ia there a way to achieve what I need? Why do I get 0 matches when I use Unicode word boundaries?

Comment: Use `let regexPattern = "(?<!\\S)@[\\w.]*"`. And right, replace `NSRegularExpression.Options.useUnicodeWordBoundaries` with `[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew it works!